# Get permutation of one array based on the size ordering of the other array

Tags: sorting, julia

Given two arrays

```
julia> a = [30, 14, 10, 21] 
julia> b = [2, 8, 24, 1]
```

I would like to get permutation indices (`perm_ixs`) for `b` such that the element size ordering of `b` corresponds to the element size ordering of `a`.

```
julia> perm_ixs =  [3, 1, 4, 2] 
julia> b[perm_ixs]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 24
  2
  1
  8
```

You can see from the above `perm_ixs`, that the element `2` in `b` is the 3rd largest element, and the 3rd largest element in `a` is `14` located at index `2`. Therefore, in the permuted `b`, the second element should have a value `2`. My current approach is shown below, and seems rather naive. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
julia> function get_size_based_permutation(a, b)
    @assert length(a) == length(b)

    # Get vectors ranking the size of elements relative to others in the vector
    # where size 1 is the largest element and size n is the smallest 
    @show sizes_a = invperm(sortperm(a; rev=true))
    @show sizes_b = invperm(sortperm(b; rev=true))

    # Map the ix of the matching size element in one array to the 
    # linearly ordered ixs of the other array
    p = collect(1:length(sizes_a))
    for (ix, size_of_ele_in_b) in enumerate(sizes_b)
        matching_size_ix = findfirst(ele -> ele == size_of_ele_in_b, sizes_a)
        p[matching_size_ix] = ix 
    end

    return p
end
julia> a = [30, 14, 10, 21] 
julia> b = [2, 8, 24, 1]
julia> perm_ixs = get_size_based_permutation(a, b)
sizes_a = invperm(sortperm(a; rev = true)) = [1, 3, 4, 2]
sizes_b = invperm(sortperm(b; rev = true)) = [3, 2, 1, 4]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 1
 4
 2

julia> b[perm_ixs]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 24
  2
  1
  8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achieving this is by first sorting `b`, and then applying the inverse of the permutation that sorts `a` to the sorted `b`. You should be able to combine that like this:

```
a = [30, 14, 10, 21] 
b = [2, 8, 24, 1]

ind_a = sortperm(a)
ind_b = sortperm(b)
perm_ixs = ind_b[invperm(ind_a)]

perm_ixs == [3,1,4,2] # true 
b[perm_ixs] == [24, 2, 1 , 8] # true
```